# Prevent Certain PID From Being Used?

Tags: linux, centos-7

When a process is started, Linux picks a PID from a pool.

I wonder whether it is possible to tell Linux not to pick certain PID without rebooting the machine as I want to disable certain PID from being picked for probably 2 seconds, and then I will lift that restriction.

**Use case**

I have like 20 C++ applications running in parallel and each of them will create a named shared memory segment called `process.[pid]`.  And since each application could crash (in case there is a bug), then I don't get a chance to clean up (removing `process.[pid]` or to be more precise, `shm_unlink()` the segement).  Due to limited memory, I would like to reclaim the resource if I find the process associated with `process.[pid]` has died already.  And so I was planning to write a script (with `cron` to kick it in periodically) to parse the named shared memory segment files and then clean up.  But I am afraid when my script is about to delete `process.1234` and OS assigns PID 1234 to my newly started C++ application, which will attempt to create `process.1234`, and then right after it is created, OS context switches to my script to delete `process.1234`.

Thanks.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: Periodically, I want my script to check whether the processes using the named shared memory segments are still alive and if not, it removes those SHM segments, during this check and removal period, I don't want the OS to reuse a PID that is dead and was previously allocated and attached to a SHM segment when my script is removing, race condition.

Comment: At least it'll fail safely – it won't cause the script to remove 'live' SHM segments, rather it'll just cause the script to leave stale segments. And chances are the condition is no longer there next time the script is run so the segments will get cleaned up anyway... But have you considered using systemd's `RemoveIPC=` to handle this automatically?

Comment: @grawity sorry, I think I missed your point.  What will fail safely?  The script?  My application will create some named segment like `process.[pid]`.  Hence, if my script can parse the name and does something like `if pid is not running; then delete the segmenet`, and the OS picks the PID for the next process (my application again) to use between the `if` and `then` statement, then my application will attempt to create, and context switch back to the script, the script deletes the segment just created, and then context switch back to my application. Then, the whole thing is wrong.

Comment: `RemoveIPC=` might not work as my application will create multiple named segments but some should stay forever.  Some should be deleted after the process crashes, or properly exits.

Comment: I would be very surprised if you can prevent the Linux kernel from using certain PIDs without making code changes to the kernel. A better approach would probably be to identify the processes using your own identifiers, use these identifiers in the named SHM segments, and keep a mapping of those identifiers to PIDs. (Also, please edit the question with your use case; phrased like this it's an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @dirkt edited my post to include the use case in detail.  what you suggested should work.  Just more clumsy in my code.  I am hoping Linux has the feature to do what I want...but u could be right that the feature doesn't exist.  Let's wait and see if someone widens our eyes.

Comment: I don't know C++ nor "shared memory segments" (therefore just a comment) but with files in `/dev/shm` the procedure may be: (1) Process A creates `/dev/shm/foo` and opens file descriptor with magic number `789`. (2) Process A removes `foo`. (3) Process B needs shared access, it finds process A somehow (4) and opens `/proc/pidA/fd/789` // When A and B exit (gracefully or not), the OS will truly forget the file. In (4) users must match, so just run only A and B as some unprivileged dedicated user. If no B ever opens its fd `789`, virtually any `fd/789` any B can open belongs to some existing A.